# Accessing username from all classes: Android

Tags: java, php, android, json, sharedpreferences

---

Background Information:

I am developing a small application. The way it works right now is the moment the app is launched, the user is prompted with the main activity. Then from there, the user clicks on the login button which prompts the login activity. Now in my login activity, I have set an Intent that gets the user's username and then stores it in the Shared Preferences. If the login is successful then the user goes to the mainloggedinpage where the user sees: [Welcome back {username}]

---

The problem is the following:

If the user is accessing the mainloggedinpage via loginactivity then you can easily see his username which is exactly what I want. But the thing is that on the main page, I have other buttons which goes to other activities. The moment the user click on any of those activities and then returns to the mainloggedin page, then all you see is: [Welcome Back {}]. His username is not displayed anymore.

---

My question:

Can anyone suggest a quick fix that will allow me to display the username so even when the user goes to another activity from the mainloggedinpage and then comes back to the mainloggedinpage, the user will still see: [Welcome Back {username}]?

---

My Code for Login Activity [This is where I am getting the username]:

```
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
         // Check for success tag
        int success;
        String username = user.getText().toString();
        String password = pass.getText().toString();
        try {
            // Building Parameters
            List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("username", username));
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password", password));

            Log.d("request!", "starting");
            // getting product details by making HTTP request
            JSONObject json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(
                   LOGIN_URL, "POST", params);

            // check your log for json response
            Log.d("Login attempt", json.toString());     

            // json success tag
            success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);
            if (success == 1) {

                Log.d("Login Successful!", json.toString());
                // save user data
                SharedPreferences sp = PreferenceManager
                        .getDefaultSharedPreferences(Login.this);
                Editor edit = sp.edit();
                edit.putString("username", username);
                edit.commit();

                Intent i = new Intent(Login.this, mainpage.class);
                i.putExtra("Welcome back, username", username);
                finish();
                startActivity(i);
                return json.getString(TAG_MESSAGE);
            }else{
                Log.d("Login Failure!", json.getString(TAG_MESSAGE));
                return json.getString(TAG_MESSAGE);

            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return null;

    }
```

---

My Code for mainloggedinActivity [This is where the username is displayed]:

```
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.mainpage);

    msuggestions = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_suggestions);
    msuggestions.setOnClickListener(this);

    mprayertimes = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btn_activityone);
    mprayertimes.setOnClickListener(this);

    mqibladirection =(Button)findViewById(R.id.btn_activitytwo);
    mqibladirection.setOnClickListener(this);

    mnewsboard = (Button) findViewById(R.id.newsboard);
    mnewsboard.setOnClickListener(this);

    mhadiths = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_activitythree);
    mhadiths.setOnClickListener(this);

    mchat = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_discussion);
    mchat.setOnClickListener(this);

    mallahnames = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_activityfour);
    mallahnames.setOnClickListener(this);

    // Get Username Start
    TextView txt_loggedName = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txt_loggedName);

    Intent intent = getIntent();
    String username  = intent.getStringExtra("Welcome back, username");
    txt_loggedName.setText(username);
    // Get Username End


    buttonLogout = (Button) findViewById(R.id.logout);
    buttonLogout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
         mPreferences = getSharedPreferences("CurrentUser", MODE_PRIVATE); 
         SharedPreferences.Editor editor=mPreferences.edit();
         editor.remove("username");
         editor.remove("password");
         editor.commit();
         Message myMessage=new Message();
                myMessage.obj="NOTSUCCESS";
                handler.sendMessage(myMessage); 
         finish();
        }
  });
```

---

Can anyone help me out so then when a user goes to the mainpage and click on one of the button and then comes back to the mainpage, it still displays his username? :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't rely on an Intent extra for storing the username, since that will only be populated directly after the user logs in.

Replace this:

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
String username  = intent.getStringExtra("Welcome back, username");
txt_loggedName.setText(username);
```

With:

```
String username = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this).getString("username", "guest");
txt_loggedName.setText("Welcome back, " + username);
```

Comment: YOU ARE AWESOME <3 Literally! It worked. I just have one little question. I had the exact same thing but the only thing was that instead of the "guest", I had put: MODE_PRIVATE. Would you mind explaining the difference please? so I can learn the reason behind it and thank you so much, it worked like a charm!

Comment: I think the 2nd parameter is the default value when the preference has not been set. You may need to do something different if the username hasn't been set. The MODE_PRIVATE doesnt apply here I think, it is used where permissions are assigned

Answer (score 0):

Instead of getting the username from the intent, You should get it from the SharedPreferences since you already saved it there.